# How to create plugin to create menu automatically in wordpress on plugin install?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a plugin, i want that, when my plugin will install, it should create menu with pages in wordpress automatically.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  before asking.

Comment: @Gaurav, Please tell me, how to write this question ?

Comment: Guys you have to try first and then ask for problem.

Comment: I am beginner in wordpress.

Comment: is there anybody, to help me for my problem ?